# apply search on results of phrase in atlas search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas

I have a `$search` stage query where I want the flow to be like this:

- phrase filters some result out
- text search happens on result of phrase

heres my query:

```
const searchObjectv2 = {
      index : "title_description_search_index",
            compound: {
                should: [
                    {
                        phrase: {
                            path: 'productId',
                            query: '[f9b03a39-cb94-4614-b3a6-7998d89915d4, 2ead21cb-644f-49d5-a9fe-7c6ff37b2935]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: {
                            path: ['title','description'],
                            query: searchKey
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

but the query is combining the results of both and giving me the final result.
My index structure is something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "description": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "productId": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "storedSource": {
    "include": [
      "productId"
    ]
  }
}
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Please elaborate "text search happens on result of phrase" part. Full text search is based on the index built on the database. There is no indices built "on result" of a stage in an aggregation pipeline, hence `$search must be the first stage of any pipeline it appears in` documented in https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/query-syntax/#behavior